# Visual Studio community 2015 and Ionic

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I was installing Visual Studio community 2015, for development of mobile apps with Ionic framework.

Now, according to various tutorials, in order to be able to use Visual Studio with Ionic, one has to include the Cordova component in the installation.

The problem is that adding this component, the space requirements for installation spike to 26 Gb, from the mere 6 Gb of a typical VS installation.

How is this possible? 20Gb just for the cordova component? It is actually a major drawback for me, since I have an ultrabook with a single 128Gb ssd..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that installing Cordova with VS 2015 ensures you have a complete environment setup to work on all the platforms.  The Android SDK, various emulators, node, git, Java JDK, and more will be installed.  It definitely is a time saver from having to install everything manually.

After you do the install you can trim down the Android SDK by removing targets / emulator images you will not be building against. If you are not deploying to Win phone 8/8.1 or Win 10 you can remove those SDKs as well.

I have a VS 2015 / Win 10 install on a 64gb bootcamp partition on a Mac air so it is doable.  When I am on the road I use it for all targets and have all SDKs installed.

Another option is using the TACO tool chain if you want which may help trim the dependencies down:
http://taco.tools

Comment: well, I think I'll keep android sdk and emulators, but definitely I don't need windows and windows phone stuff. How can I safely uninstall them?

Comment: You can use add/remove programs option from control panel and either use the VS setup program or remove the Windows Software Development kit / Phone kits directly from the list.